# How to clean up tables that don't belong into mysql/mysql database?

Tags: mysql

It seems that a *.sql file I recently imported had `use mysql` instead of `use dbname`. Now the `mysql` database contains a large number of tables which don't belong there.

Is there an easy/efficient way to clean this up?

---

Note: I am using MariaDB, but I think a generic answer would be more useful for others.

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.10-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clean way...

```
USE MyDatabase;
RENAME TABLE mysql.mytable1 TO mytable1;
RENAME TABLE mysql.mytable2 TO mytable2;
```

etc.

You said "large number"... You could get the list thus:

```
SELECT CONCAT('RENAME TABLE mysql.', TABLE_NAME, ' TO ', TABLENAME, ';')
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE schema_name = 'mysql';
```

But be *very careful* not to rename the system tables!

Comment: Ok.. Where could I find a list of the "correct" tables in the mysql database?

Comment: @donquixote: [The mysql Database Tables - MariaDB Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/the-mysql-database-tables/) (no idea if that list is exhaustive, though – looks like it should be but I'm not sure)

Comment: @donquixote you could also grep for them in your most recent backup file from before the mistake was made.